# sed used in the function of the bash script fails

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I use this bash script `sed_no_ocr.sh` which has no `x` property (i.e. `ls -al sed_no_ocr.sh` shows `-rw-r--r--`):

```bash
#! /bin/bash
file=$1
concatenation(){
    echo "sed -i -r -e 's/($1) ($2)/\1\2/;p' $file"
    sed -i -r -e 's/($1) ($2)/\1\2/;p' $file
}
concatenation "bypas" "sAfromALUinWB" $file
```

Input file `E4.13.4_orig.v`:

```
...
assign bypas sAfromALUinWB = (IDEXrs1 == MEMWBrd) && (IDEXrs1 != 0) &&
...
```

I use `sed 4.9`. But the script **fails** to change the input file when running `. ../sed_no_ocr.sh E4.13.4_orig.v`. Running `sed -r -e 's/(bypas) (sAfromALUinWB)/\1\2/p' E4.13.4_orig.v` in bash **works**.

Q: how to make above `concatenation` function works in the bash script?

Comment: In single quotes (`'`) the variables `$1`...  are not intrepretted

Comment: And `file` is `$3`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice the differences between single quotes and double quotes. As `man bash` says "Enclosing  characters  in  single  quotes **preserves the literal value** of each character within the quotes", maybe I should avoid use single quotes as the default quotes.

Comment: This question seems also duplicate in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23850894/21294350) which I found later.

Comment: Yep, the way in SO is good, maybe you can reconsider and use `awk`

Comment: "_maybe I should avoid use single quotes as the default quotes_" - not necessarily. If you want to handle literal strings then single quotes are correct. If you want to interpolate variables (`$name`) and command outputs (`$(date)`) you should use double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for above 2 comments. 1. Yes. Both `awk` and `sed` are helpful to manipulate with texts 2. Sorry for saying too absolute. I will take care when choosing whether to use single quotes or double quotes.